# Clarification of symbols in an URL %\

Tags: url, escaping, uri, openstack-nova

What is the purpose of the %\ in the following URL?

```
http://controller:8774/v2/%\(tenant_id\)s
```

I'm very new with Linux but i understand that the forward slash \ is often used as an escape character. I also know that the % symbol is used as an escape character in URL encoding. Not sure how the combination of %\ works?

It is used to create an OpenStack nova API. The exact command is

`openstack endpoint create --region RegionOne \
  compute public http://controller:8774/v2/%\(tenant_id\)s`

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the context for this? Is this typed in a command line or a shell script, or somewhere else? (By intuition, `%\ ` is nothing; `\(` and `\)` are escapes for parentheses that would otherwise be taken to have special meaning to shell).

Comment: Where did u found such URL? % is followed by a number usually

Answer (score 0):

As I surmised, the URL is `"http://controller:8774/v2/%(tenant_id)s"`. Quoted, it works like it is supposed to:

```
$ echo "http://controller:8774/v2/%(tenant_id)s"
http://controller:8774/v2/%(tenant_id)s

$ echo 'http://controller:8774/v2/%(tenant_id)s'
http://controller:8774/v2/%(tenant_id)s
```

Escaped works as well:

```
$ echo http://controller:8774/v2/%\(tenant_id\)s
http://controller:8774/v2/%(tenant_id)s
```

But if you don't do *something* to remove the special meaning from the parentheses, `bash` will complain:

```
$ echo http://controller:8774/v2/%(tenant_id)s
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

This is because `bash` uses parentheses to group commands into subprocesses:

```
$ (echo bear && echo aardvark) | sort
aardvark
bear
```

and thus an open parenthesis can't come anywhere where you can't start a command.

Meanwhile, the meaning of `%(...)` is specific to openstack; I believe it is a variable that will be replaced *before* the URL is used as an actual URL; so it is more of an URL template than an actual URL.